# Google client api not working in iphone ( safari browser)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, google-api-client

I am using Google Client api for javscript in my phonegap application to login to Google account.

It works fine with the android browsers but it doesn't work in iphone. The page just freezes after i login.

Can anyone let me know if there is something i need to do to make it work?

i have already tried by using immediate=false option.

Comment: What domains have you whitelisted in the PhoneGap config?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the login page freezes after authorizing the app is because of the *'redirect_uri'* parameter in the auth url.

After authorizing the app, Google api sends the authCode back as parameter to the 'redirect_uri' specified. Since i have mentioned `localhost` as the 'redirect_uri', safari browser could not redirect to `localhost` and it froze. Though it worked in android browser.

So i have created a new client ID, *'Client ID for web applications'* and gave my server url as the *'Authorized redirect uri'* and used the same in the Google client auth url and it worked in both android and ios.

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

I also found this:  [`http://www.itsalif.info/content/oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery`](http://www.itsalif.info/content/oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery)

I know when I worked with the Google API with Trello there was a whole lot of key passing going on.  So perhaps you need to make sure your keys are set up correctly.   But beyond that, I would need a better explanation of your problem, specifics would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to stack! As a helpful pointer, asking for more details and adding simply links is better as comments on the question reserving an answer for a solution once the details have been clarified.  Hope that helps.